# Angular2 test if component has proper selector

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular-components

Is there any possibility in Angular2 to verify component selector with unit test?

e.g.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<p>test</p>'
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

and

```
....
it(`Component should have selector 'my-component'`, () => {
    expect(component.selector).toBe('my-component');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reflect` metadata is used by Angular DI to store and retrieve decorator data.

It is possible to get metadata from the class and assert it:

```
  const [componentDecorator] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', MyComponentClass);

  expect(componentDecorator.selector).toBe('my-component');
```

Where `Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ...)` returns an array of class annotations.

This requires `reflect-metadata` **or** `core-js/es7/reflect` polyfills to be loaded. This polyfill is Angular prerequisite.

Comment: What should I import in order to use the `Reflect.getOwnMetadata` method?

Comment: You need to have https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata polyfill loaded. It is a prerequisite for Angular, so it's most likely there already.

Comment: I had to add `import {} from 'reflect-metadata';`. Could you add it to your answer? I will accept it then. Could you also tell me why it has to be `[componentDecorator]` and not just `componentDecorator`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you had to did it, this is a polyfill that is required by Angular to work. Any way, the proper place to include polyfills is test runner config (is it Karma?), not spec file. As the answer says, *Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ...) returns an array of class annotations*. Considering that there was only @Component decorator on component class (usually it is so), component decorator is 0 element of the array.