# Get annotated components in angular4

Tags: angular

Is it possible that get annotated components or services in angular 4?

In java we can do that by reflections.

```
Reflections reflections = new 
Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<?>> annotated = 
reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class);

for (Class<?> controller : annotated) {
    RequestMapping request = 
controller.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    String mapping = request.name();
}
```

I want to anotate(with id) some services then want to get service instance by id.

Comment: Is this a thing you're asking about, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183032/3731501 ? It's not clear what you mean, and Java example doesn't help much.